# Storing and fetching large amounts of data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to maintain around 50 million records in the database, and I have to get at least 100 000 records at any point of time. How it is possible? How my database design should be?

Comment: Shouldn't be any problems. Show us your database design attempt.

Comment: Just for others who don't know: 1 Crore is 10 million.

Comment: Please, for the future - use **internationally known** units of measure - thousand, million, billion etc. - thank you

Comment: You can partition table data. If it is possible use a cluster index on fetching criteria. This will enable page by page reading more effective instead of fetching a page for a single row data. You can use an in-memory database version of SQL Server to get rid of disk IO

Answer (score 0):

Use normalization [Normalization concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Store everything in a single table is generally a bad idea as that table becomes huge size.